# Microsoft Graph - get invalid id when getting message mime

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a certain message id (got it after listing user messages), if I'm sending a request to `/users/{user_id}/messages/{message_id}` then I get a valid response (200, with all of the mail's
properties).

However, when I try to get the actual mime behind this message, by sending a request to `/users/{user_id}/messages/{message_id}/$value` then I get a 400 (bad request) status code with the following error:

`'{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidId","message":"The Id is invalid."}}'`

I tried using both immutable id and the default id - they both get the same response.

This only happens for some of the messages, i.e. using the same method for other messages work just fine.

I think it started happening a couple of weeks ago.

Any idea why is this happening? way to get around it?

Thanks

Comment: Would you kindly share request-id and error message so we can help debug?

Comment: I dont have a requestid, I've specified in the question the response I get, I know it does not contain a lot of info but that's all I get back from Graph...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved automatically as of 25/5/21.
I guess that it was an issue with Graph, and someone there finally fixed it after couple of weeks.